How to configure App Clip Only XCode project
I have an App, and I want to publish an App Clip in addition to that app. Due to size restrictions I cannot share any of my assets or code, so I made a new XCode project (for background, the original project is a build from Unity, so it would be inconvenient to link them into one XCode project).
I have set up an XCode project with an App Clip, then deleted the main App from it, and now I want to distribute the App Clip to XCode.
I could not push to the App Store in the organizer (only 'custom' available under 'method for distribution', then I can only select 'Built Products' or 'Archive', no upload to App Store, see screenshot)

until I found that my App Clip target (the only target in my project) had Build Settings -> Deployment -> Skip Install set to Yes. When I turn that to No, in the Organizer when pushing to App Store Connect, it now tries to create a new App instead of connecting it to the already existing app (see next screenshot, actual bunlde id removed but it matches)

The already existing app has a bundle id io.mycompany.maypp, and the app clip has io.mycompany.myapp.Clip
Is what I am trying even possible, or do the main app and app clip need to be published in the same XCode project? Which settings do I need for this?
